# on ms-sql server, what is the best tool to get all the dependencies between all the objects?

Tags: sql-server-2008, documentation, dependencies

im looking for a tool the get an info for documentation about the dependencies between the objects like tables, views, functions, triggers, procedures. the ssms shows some dependencies but i can't get them out for documentation and as microsoft says thei are not comprehensive.

I found a tool-suite "sqltoolbelt" with a module called Dependency Tracker, does anybody know it and how is the experience?

Peace

Ice

Comment: I wrote a lengthy post on dependencies in 2008 here.  If you want to learn how the dependency model works natively it may be useful reading: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would second the shout for RedGate SQL Dependency Tracker.

Just some more information about this product, you can visually map all of your database or filter by specific object types or names. The resulting diagrams have 5 different styles and all of them can be output to PDF, XML or as an image file.

Personally I would seriously recommend you look at the Comparison Bundle of SQL Compare, SQL Data Compare, Dependency Tracker and SQL Packager. All great tools to have, and no I don't work for RedGate, I have just found their tools invaluable for the past 3 years...

Answer (score 0):

Red Gate tools are highly recommended. I've use the Sql Toolbelt so it gets my thumbs up.

There is also SQL Search by Red Gate which is a new (free) tool - if you want to get a feel for what the Red Gate tools are like to use, either download that or the trial version of other tools. You'll soon get a feel for what their tools are like to use.