# What is good way of doing Database Unit testing

Tags: sql, unit-testing, database-testing

We are using Power Designer for Database Modelling and whenever something is changed in model 
(column name, datatypes etc) have go back and test all depended stored procedures and fix them accordingly.

What would be the best tool to do unit testing of database.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [DBFit](http://benilovj.github.com/dbfit) (open source) for unit testing stored procs.

To approach the problem from a different angle, if you're using SQL Server, you might find the newly-released (free) [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Search/index.htm) a useful tool for tracking down dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/) - it's definitely worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

If this is MS-SQL, someone just asked: [`what is the best tool to get all the dependencies between all the objects?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205952/on-ms-sql-server-what-is-the-best-tool-to-get-all-the-dependencies-between-all-t).